# Improve fluidity on a big data graphic - d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I got three tree's with subparts, and when I click, it take like 1.4s to do the movement, so my question is how can i improve the fluidity of these movement when I click ? 
I have already deleted all possible animations to be more fluid.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Graphique DPGF</title>
    <style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#div { display: table-row; }
#div .cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}


#tabcmp {
    font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#moteur {
    font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

#form {
    font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;   
}        


</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<br><p id="form">
        <label for="ent1">Entreprise 1 :</label>
            <select name="ent1" id="ent1">
            </select>
        <label style="margin-left:100px;" for="ent2">Entreprise 2 :</label>
            <select name="ent2" id="ent2">
            </select>
    <input style="margin-left:100px;" type="radio" name="ecart" id="abs" value="abs">
    <label for="abs">Absolus</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ecart" id="rel" value="rel">
    <label for="rel">Relatifs</label>
    <button id="button" style="margin-left:100px;">Actualiser</button>
    </p><br>
    <center id="tabcmp">Tableau comparatif</center>
<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 400,
    barHeight = 20,
    barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;

var cursorX;
var click_mult;
var cursorY;
//stack_nb variable
var nb_data = [
    [], [], []
];
var ent = 0;

document.onmousemove = function(e){
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;
    }

var i = 0,
    duration = 0,
    root;

var all_path = [];
all_path[0] = "leJson.json";
all_path[1] = "leJson.json";
all_path[2] = "leJson.json";

var path = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        path[i] = all_path[i];
path[2] = "leJson.json"; 
create_a_tree_obj(path);

function multiple_click() {
    //onmousemove = function(e){console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY)}
    if (cursorX >= 0 && cursorX < 600) {
        simulateClick(cursorX + 600 - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
        simulateClick(cursorX + 1200 - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
    }
    else if (cursorX >= 600 && cursorX < 1200) {
        simulateClick(cursorX - 600 - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
        simulateClick(cursorX + 600 - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
    }
    else if (cursorX >= 1200) {
        simulateClick(cursorX - 600 - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
        simulateClick(cursorX - 1200 - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
    }
    else
        console.log("no , cursorX = " + cursorX + " , cursorY = " + cursorY);
}

function add_up_svgs() {
    var tmp;
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0; nb_data[2][i]; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById("abs").checked) {
                tmp = Number(nb_data[0][i].innerHTML) - Number(nb_data[1][i].innerHTML);
                if (tmp >= 0)
                    nb_data[2][i].innerHTML = "+" + tmp.toFixed(1);
                else
                    nb_data[2][i].innerHTML = "" + tmp.toFixed(1);
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("rel").checked) {
                tmp = (Number(nb_data[0][i].innerHTML) - Number(nb_data[1][i].innerHTML)) / Number(nb_data[0][i].innerHTML) * 100;
                if (tmp >= 0)
                    nb_data[2][i].innerHTML = "+" + tmp.toFixed(1) + " %";
                else
                    nb_data[2][i].innerHTML = "" + tmp.toFixed(1) + " %";

            }
            else {
                tmp = Number(nb_data[0][i].innerHTML) - Number(nb_data[1][i].innerHTML);
                if (tmp >= 0)
                    nb_data[2][i].innerHTML = "+" + tmp.toFixed(1);
                else
                    nb_data[2][i].innerHTML = "" + tmp.toFixed(1);
            }
            nb_data[2][i].setAttribute("x", (288 - nb_data[2][i].innerHTML.length * 6) - 7);
        }
    }, 100);
}

function retrieve_content_svgs(all_g, i) {
    var all_aftertext = all_g.selectAll(".node tspan.aftertext"); //On récupère tout les aftertext, rect qui contient des nombres.
    var nodelist_tmp = Object.values(all_aftertext)[0][0]; //Conversion d'object à nodelist
    nb_data[i] = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist_tmp); //Conversion Nodelist a array
}   

function create_a_tree_obj(path) {
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    var cell;
    var svg_array = [];

    if (i === 0) {
        div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "div");
    }
    for (i ; path[i]; i++) {
        var nb_ent = i + 1;
        cell = div.append("div").attr("class", "cell").attr("id", "cell" + i);
        svg_array[i] = cell.append("svg")
        .attr("id", "d" + i)
        .attr("width", 600) // + margin.left + margin.right)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i);
    }
    //Set des classe et nom pour le dernière arbre du total.
    cell.attr("class", "total").attr("id", "total");
    cell.select("#title").text("Comparatif");
    //Addition des deux svg dans le total.
    add_up_svgs();
    //Appel de create_ent_form, qui permet d'ajouter le choix des entreprises en haut de la page.    
    if (ent === 0) {
            create_ent_form(all_path);    
            ent++;
    }
}

function create_ent_form(all_path) {
    var ent1 = document.getElementById("ent1");
    var ent2 = document.getElementById("ent2");
    for (var i = 0; all_path[i]; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.innerHTML = all_path[i];
        ent1.append(opt);
    }
    for (var i = 0; all_path[i]; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.innerHTML = all_path[i];
        ent2.append(opt);
    }
}    

function button_clicked() {
    var path_tmp = [];
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        path_tmp[0] = document.getElementById("ent1").options[document.getElementById("ent1").selectedIndex].text;
        path_tmp[1] = document.getElementById("ent2").options[document.getElementById("ent2").selectedIndex].text;
        path_tmp[2] = path_tmp[0];
        remove_and_replace(path_tmp);
        return;
    });
}

function remove_and_replace(new_path) {
    var div = d3.select("#div");
    div.remove();
    create_a_tree_obj(new_path);
}
function add_the_tree_graph(svg_array, path, i) {
    var root = [];

    d3.json(path[i], function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;
        root[i] = d3.hierarchy(json);
        root[i].x0 = 0;
        root[i].y0 = 0;
        update(root[i], svg_array[i], "d" + i, root, 0);
        retrieve_content_svgs(svg_array[i], i);
    });
}    

function update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources, check) {
  // Compute the flattened node list.
    var nodes = source.descendants();
    var height = Math.max(50, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    document.getElementById(svg_id).setAttribute("height", height);
    d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");

  // Compute the "layout". TODO https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/67
  var index = -1;
  source.eachBefore(function(n) {
    n.x = ++index * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 20;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg_var.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function (d) {
          return 'node ' + (d.children ? '' : 'child'); 
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0);
console.log(nodeEnter);
  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources, 1); //recursion pour re-afficher la page dynamiquement.
      click_mult = 1;
      return;
    });
    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 3.5)
    .attr("dx", 5.5)
    .each(function (d) {
    if(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|') > -1) {
        var beforeText = d.data.attributes.substr(0,   d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')).trim(),
        afterText = d.data.attributes.substr(d.data.attributes.indexOf('|')+1, d.data.attributes.length).trim();
        d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('beforetext', true).text(beforeText);
        var afterTextSpan = d3.select(this).append('tspan').classed('aftertext', true).attr("id", "afterText").text(afterText);
        // position aftertext
        afterTextSpan.attr('x', (288 - afterText.length * 6) - 5);
    } else {
        d3.select(this).text(d.data.attributes);
    }
  });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
    nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);
    node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
}
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    var s = d3.select(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
    s.on("click")(s.datum());
}

//Click multiple
setInterval(function(e){
    if (click_mult === 1) {
        multiple_click();
        click_mult = 0;
    }
    //console.log("X = " + cursorX + " Y = " + cursorY);
}, 1);

setInterval(button_clicked(), 1);

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

And here is the leJson.json file :

[leJson.json](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqTGFiiEZzRVkzu3MLZ0kA5YfjsP) - the file was too long to copy it here